# How to Use Mail Merge Template file with PHP

Tags: php, html, mailmerge

As the title suggest, I have never used mail merge before, and don't even know if this is possible?

Basically I have template created in mail merge, my question is I don't know how to use this with PHP to send mail to list of clients just like RSS mail, i just want to know if this is possible or not, and if possible what is the procedure for doing that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been looking for the same thing and I ran across this article:

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?50825-How-to-do-Mail-Merge-with-php-and-MySQL

Essentially they suggest using the [file()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) function to pull the file contents into an array and then loop on the array with str_replace().  Obviously this means that the strings you want to replace need to stand out (the questioner was using % at the beginning and end of each string), but if I'm not mistaken mail merge tags are identified with '<< >>'.

Good luck!